# Hard drive not recognized in bios after installing linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

Hard drive and boot not recognized in bios after installing Ubuntu 20.04

I tried to create partitions on the disk (/, /home, etc) but still the bios does not see the disk. At the same time, the disk is perfectly recognized in GParted.

I tried copying files to cdrom/EFI/BOOT directory from live-usb but that didn't work either

I don`t have installed Windows in my laptop, only Linux

Comment: The files should be copied to `/boot/efi` and not `cdrom/EFI/BOOT`

Comment: The next step would be to use bootrepair. Use a live session, select "try ubuntu without installing", and then use the [2nd option listed on this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install Bootrepair